# Powershell convert to SecureString

Tags: powershell, exchange-management-shell

This is what I'm working on

```
$First = Read-Host "Enter First Name"
$Last = Read-Host "Enter Last Name"
$FirstIntitial = $First.Substring(0,1)
$LastInitial = $Last.Substring(0,1)
$FirstLastInitial = $FirstIntitial.ToUpper()+$LastInitial.ToUpper()
$Location = Read-Host "Enter Location"
$Department = Read-Host "Enter Department"
$Database
$Password = $FirstLastInitial+"Company"
Write-Host $Password
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

When i run it I get the error:

> "Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Password'.
>   Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type
>   "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString"

Im very new to powershell and this is written based on what ive found on google. How am I supposed to convert the password to a securestring?

Comment: I do not get errors either. At this point knowing you environment might be helpful. What version of PowerShell and what OS? Or if nothing else close your scripting session. Open a new one and paste in the code from the question here and run it again. Might be nice to know what _you_ are typing in for you tests.... in case the answer is there.

Comment: Im testing it on a server 2008 server. I am running it through the exchange management shell. The name I am testing it with is Jack Smith.

Comment: Powershell version? Can you run this on different systems?

Comment: `"JSCompany" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force` Does this code even work for you? Shouldnt matter that you are running in EMS but I just ran this one mine and didnt get an issue there.

Comment: the exchange management shell is running PSVersion 2.0

Comment: It works if i type it by itself but when i run it as part of the script i get the error. Im running the script by calling it from the EMS cmd line, c:\\pathtoscript\scriptname.ps1

Comment: That would tell me there is something wrong with the script. If you copy and paste what you have here into a new script and run it does it work?

Comment: Just to be sure, because things like this happen even to the best: Are you double sure, that you use `$SecurePassword` later in your script instead of `$Password`?

Comment: I found the error. Later in my script i was using $SecurePassword with quotes around it to set the users password but I Shouldnt have used the quotes.